# Spring Boot Security - How to disable access to endpoints for swagger ui page if the user is not authenticated with Oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui

I am trying to disable access to `"/v2/api-docs"` end point if the user is not authenticated with Oauth2 (the authorize button on swagger ui page).

1. My spring security configuration is like the following:

   @Configuration
   @EnableResourceServer
   public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   ```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/api/health", "/api/info").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/v1/**").
                authenticated();
    }
   ```

   }
2. and this class where I configure swagger Oauth2 authentication

   ```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
     private static final String USER_INVALID = "User Name or Password is invalid";
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated").allowFormAuthenticationForClients().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.tokenStore(new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource)).authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.PUT).exceptionTranslator(ex -> ResponseEntity.status(
                        HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(OAuth2Exception.create(OAuth2Exception.UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT, USER_INVALID))).;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
   ```

   }
3. in the application.properties I add the following properties:

> ```
> host.full.dns.auth.link=http://oauthserver.example.com:8081
> app.client.id=test-client
> app.client.secret=clientSecret
> auth.server.schem=http
> ```

Any ideas how can I disable access to api-docs if the user is not authenticated with Oauth2 ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The swagger-ui.html call the `/v2/api-docs` to fill the page with
   senstive information. So, I override `doFilterInternal` from
   `OncePerRequestFilter`. if the swagger-ui call the documentation
   then the call will pass. If the user try to call the end point of
   the documentation directly it will display bad request.

   @Component
   public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
   @Override
   protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
   String path = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
   String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Referer");
   if ("/v2/api-docs".equals(path) && authorization.isEmpty()) {
   httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "Invalid Locale");
   return;
   }
   filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
   }
   }

The
swagger-ui.html file is now static ressource. and for the
swagger-ui.html is already protected  on the swagger-ui.html I
changed the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
      var auth = window.sessionStorage.getItem("Authorization");
      if (url && url.length > 1) {
        url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
      } else if (auth) {
        url = "/v2/api-docs";
      }
// some code
      window.swaggerUi.load();
      swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("oauth2schema",new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization",'Bearer '+auth,"header"));

      function log() {
        if ('console' in window) {
          console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
      }
```